# where to get Intel bios source code?

Tags: x86, intel, bios

I want to learn Intel BIOS. So where I can get open source code
and some development guide? from the link http://www.crn.com/news/applications-os/21401337/intel-bios-code-goes-open-source.htm , I know Intel has already opened BIOS source, but I don't know how to get it.

Answer (score 7):

The open source backbone of the modern UEFI BIOS is called *Tiano*. Look at the [Tianocore project](http://www.tianocore.org/).

Note that *Tiano* is just the underlying code framework of UEFI. It is missing the code to initialize your specific chipset. It also doesn't have the setup menu code. That stuff is not open source and is specific to the BIOS vendors (AMI, Phoenix, Insyde, etc). Those vendors incorporate *Tiano* into their products. You would have to license the BIOS source for your platform from them (at considerable cost).

If you are looking for a "complete" open source BIOS that you can compile and load onto your computer, look at the [Coreboot project](https://www.coreboot.org/).